# what does [undefined reference to `SetLastError@4'] mean?

Tags: c++, gcc, ld

I use mingw-w64 to deploy C++ on windows, everything is normal except when I use the library function, the following problems will be reported at runtime

```
d:/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(mbrscan.o):(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `SetLastError@4'
d:/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(wcharmap.o):(.text+0x208): undefined reference to `WideCharToMultiByte@32'
d:/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingwex.a(codeset.o):(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `GetCPInfo@8'
d:/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingwex.a(codeset.o):(.text+0x143): undefined reference to `GetCPInfo@8'
d:/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/libgcc_eh.a(emutls.o): in function `_gthread_key_create':
/home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libgcc/./gthr-default.h:590: undefined reference to `TlsAlloc@0'       
d:/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: /home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libgcc/./gthr-default.h:597: undefined reference to `__mingwthr_key_dtor'
d:/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/libgcc_eh.a(emutls.o): in function `_gthread_getspecific':
/home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libgcc/./gthr-default.h:621: undefined reference to `SetLastError@4'   
d:/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/mingw-w64/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/libgcc_eh.a(emutls.o): in function `_gthread_setspecific':
/home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libgcc/./gthr-default.h:629: undefined reference to `TlsSetValue@8'    
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What caused this？Can u help me solve it?

--

A minimal example that reproduces what I believe is the problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  cout << to_string(42) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Link with MinGW GCC 9.2.0

```
C:\Users\dash\repos\link-error>g++ --version
g++ (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


C:\Users\dash\repos\link-error>g++ main.cpp -o main
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(mbrscan.o):(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `SetLastError@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(wcharmap.o):(.text+0x208): undefined reference to `WideCharToMultiByte@32'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingwex.a(codeset.o):(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `GetCPInfo@8'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingwex.a(codeset.o):(.text+0x143): undefined reference to `GetCPInfo@8'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: How do you compile your code?

Comment: I run code on  vscode

Comment: VSCode needs instructions how to compile the code. I never used it, but I guess it would be a Makefile, CMake or some own system that runs `gcc` on it's own. Whatever it is, the issue is there.

Comment: I see, I will debug these aspects. thank you very much

Comment: You should considering to use any build system tool, e.g. [cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

While you tag your question `gcc`, the error is actually from `ld`, which is the linker.

You compile something (which you didn't show the command) and the linker complains for `SetLastError@4`. My bet is there is a function `SetLastError()` being used in the code (mbrscan.c?) but you didn't include the relevant object code or library for your linker.

Please check if you missed any library (`-l` flag in gcc), or any `*.o` file in your compile command.

Comment: oh i see, let me check it out.Thank u!

Comment: this is the command : `D:\mingw-w64\bin\g++.exe -g d:\VSProject\test.cpp -o d:\VSProject\test.exe -ggdb3 -Wall -static-libgcc -std=c++17 -finput-charset=UTF-8 -fexec-charset=GB18030 '-D _USE_MATH_DEFINES'` Is there missing something about `ld`?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue which drove me crazy. But solution is easy (thankfully):
MinGW cannot link because the libraries are just not installed.
Solution:

- Enter command line `Start->cmd`
- type `mingw-get`
- search for `mingw32-libmingwex` under `MinGW Standard Libraries`
- activate both `mingw32-libmingwex-dll` and `mingw32-libmingwex-dev`
- go to `Installation->Apply Changes`

Done!

PS: I propose to change topic of this thread to "MinGW - linker error" or similar with according tags...